# Win XP Screen saver / power management not working

Tags: windows-xp, display, power-management

I have a PC running Win XP, and even though I have the power management set to turn off the monitor after 10 minutes, and I have the windows screen saver set up, many times they never kick in.  I come home or wake up to a monitor that is fully on so perhaps some process is keeping the PC active?  Of course it's not consistent and hard to re-produce when I want to.

Comment: Perhaps someone at home turns it on while you're not home.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging devices (like the mouse) when you leave the PC and seeing if the problem persists?  You can probably figure out what is resetting the timer that way.  Some mice are so sensitive that a fan in the room will cause  registered movement.

Comment: See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/387627/any-way-to-detect-what-is-disabling-the-screensaver) post.

Answer (score 0):

This might help figure out a setting you have misplaced. It's hard to tell without checking all your settings.

http://tips.oncomputers.info/archives2003/0303/2003-mar-09.htm